# How to get unweighted counts of a variable versus weighted counts of a variable

Tags: r, count, weighted

I'm working on a project where I need to find the total number of unweighted counts of a variable as well as a weighted count of another variable. For the unweighted counts, I used

```r
dat %>%
  count(citizen, wt = NULL, sort = FALSE)
```

which seems right to me but I'm not sure how to find the weighted count. I'm just starting out with R so I'm sure this seems like a super basic question but I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You can specify the `wt` with the column name

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).